# Getting a black overlay with text when hovering over an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I searched all over for this and I found a couple of solutions, but I cannot get this to work in my application. What I am trying to do is to get a black-overlay over an image when hovered over and then text to appear. Ideally I want the text to have a border that looks like a button.

I want this to work with my scale on hover as well. For some reason on my actual page, when hovering over an image, it does nothing but scale. It doesn't turn the parent div the gray color.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
$('.home-img-block').find('img').each(function() {
   var imgClass = (this.width / this.height > 1) ? 'wide' : 'tall';
   console.log(imgClass);
   $(this).addClass(imgClass);
 });
```

```css
#home-img-blocks {
 width: 100%;
 height: 600px;
}

.home-img-block {
 width: 33.33%;
 /*height: 100%;*/
 display: inline-block;
 overflow: hidden;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.home-img-block:after {
    content: attr(data-content);
    color:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    top:0; left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.home-img-block:hover:after {
    opacity:1;
}
.home-img-block img{
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
    -o-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.home-img-block:hover img{
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
    transform:scale(1.25);
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 width: 33.33%;
 max-height: 100%;
}
.home-img-block img.wide {
 max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
.home-img-block img.tall {
 max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
 width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home-img-blocks">
 <div data-content="FIND OUT MORE" class="home-img-block"><img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/test1.jpg"></div><div class="home-img-block"><img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/test2.jpg">
   </div><div class="home-img-block"><img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/test3.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this is what you want. Check this out. Added an overlay class for black overlay.

```js
$('.home-img-block').find('img').each(function() {
  var imgClass = (this.width / this.height > 1) ? 'wide' : 'tall';
  console.log(imgClass);
  $(this).addClass(imgClass);
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#home-img-blocks {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}

.home-img-block {
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  /*height: 100%;*/
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.home-img-block:hover .overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.home-img-block:after {
  content: attr(data-content);
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.home-img-block:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.home-img-block img {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  /* IE 9 */
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  /* Opera */
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.home-img-block:hover img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transform: scale(1.25);
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-transform: scale(1.25);
  /* IE 9 */
  -o-transform: scale(1.25);
  /* Opera */
  transform: scale(1.25);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 33.33%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.home-img-block img.wide {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.home-img-block img.tall {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home-img-blocks">
  <div data-content="FIND OUT MORE" class="home-img-block">
    <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/test1.jpg">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
  <div data-content="FIND OUT" class="home-img-block">
    <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/test2.jpg">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
  <div data-content="FIND" class="home-img-block">
    <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/test3.jpg">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect except it seems the black overlay enlarges the images a little bit. How would I prevent that?

Comment: @Becky you don't want to scale the image on hover? or scale a little bit ?

Comment: I want the image to scale. Just the black overlay exceeds past the image size.

Comment: Understand. I will check this and get back to you :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a few things in your css this is why you are not getting the desired affect that you are looking for. You needed to add position relative to the .home-img-block class and then some of your stuff was just placed wrong giving a wierd shaking thing when hovering over it.

Here is a link to jsfiddle so you can mess around with it :

https://jsfiddle.net/kriscoulson/y32ekgdm/

```css
#home-img-blocks {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}

.home-img-block {
  width: 33.33%;
  /*height: 100%;*/
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
.home-img-block:after {
  content: attr(data-content);
  color:#fff;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%; height:100%;
  top:0; left:0;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  opacity:0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.home-img-block:hover:after {
  opacity:1;
}
.home-img-block img{
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; Safari and Chrome
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease; Firefox
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease; IE 9
  -o-transition: all 1s ease; Opera
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.home-img-block:hover img{
  transform:scale(1.25);
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.home-img-block img.wide {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.home-img-block img.tall {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an issue with the css. Mainly at these points:

```
home-img-block:hover img
```

and

```
.home-img-block img
```

Since, `.home-img-block` is wrapping the HTML. You dont have to be specific. And plus the first CSS line for `hover` set seems to be wrong. I have forked the code to a fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/kuape5np/

Could you confirm, is that you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out I hope you are looking for same

```css
.home-img-block {
 width: 33.33%;
 display: inline-block;
 overflow: hidden;
 cursor: pointer;
     position: relative;
}

.home-img-block:hover:after {
    opacity:1;
}
.home-img-block img{
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
    -o-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all 1s ease;
 width: 100%;
}
.home-img-block:hover img{
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
    transform:scale(1.25);
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 max-height: 100%;
}
.home-img-block:after {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
    -o-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.hover {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50% , -50%);
    opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
    -o-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.hover h2 {
 color:#fff;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
    -o-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.home-img-block:hover:after,.home-img-block:hover .hover, .home-img-block:hover .hover h2 {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
    <div id="home-img-blocks">
 <div class="home-img-block">
     <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/test1.jpg">
  <div class="hover">
    <h2>FIND OUT MORE</h2>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```